# Fourier coefficient of close functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, characters, cyclic-groups

Let $p$ be some prime. Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the cyclic group of order $p$. Let $f, g \colon \mathbb{Z}_p \to \{\pm 1\}$ be two functions. Recall that the Fourier transform is defined as
$$ f(x) = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p}\widehat f(\alpha) \cdot \chi_\alpha(x)$$
where $\chi_\alpha(x) = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p} \cdot  \alpha x}$ is the character function.

Suppose we are given the following:

(1) $f,g$ have correlation ($\gamma > 0$ is some parameter):
$$ | \langle f, g \rangle | = | \mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mathbb{Z}_p}{f(x) \cdot g(x)} | \geq \gamma$$

(2) for some character $\chi_\beta \colon \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{C}$, $| \widehat f(\beta) | \geq \tau$ (for some parameter $\tau \in[0,1]$)

What can be said about $\widehat{g}(\beta)$ with respect to $\gamma, \tau$?

Comment: can you define the character and the transform explicitly for readability

Comment: @kodlu added :)

Comment: You wrote the formula finding $f$ in terms of $\hat{f}$, instead of defining $\hat{f}$.

Comment: What are the relations you are expecting between $\tau,\gamma$? One may take $g$ to be a specific character (say different than $\beta$), hence you know explicitly what it is the correlation and what it means for $f$, but your only info is about the coefficient in $\beta$... In particular $\hat{g}(\beta)$ may be $0$.